# Trying to install NWipe 0.25

Tags: software-installation

I'm tying to get NWipe .25 installed on a clean 19.04 install. When I do so it says its installing .25, but then reports .24:

```
root@SuperNuker:/home/jenscom# apt install nwipe
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  nwipe
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 32.8 kB of archives.
After this operation, 97.3 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco/universe amd64 nwipe amd64 0.25-1 [32.8 kB]
Fetched 32.8 kB in 1s (53.8 kB/s)
Selecting previously unselected package nwipe.
(Reading database ... 253912 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../nwipe_0.25-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking nwipe (0.25-1) ...
Setting up nwipe (0.25-1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.5-2) ...
root@SuperNuker:/home/jenscom# nwipe -V
nwipe version 0.24
root@SuperNuker:/home/jenscom#
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

You are doing nothing wrong. It was a bug in nwipe that reported the incorrect version. See https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nwipe/+bug/1835678/comments/2

Fixed in nwipe 0.26